# Format numerical string to price

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number variable that will always only provide digits like this:
249837

How can I format the string like this in javascript?
2,498.37

Edit: This is a bit more difficult from other questions because the last 2 digits in the input are cents with no periods in the variable.

Comment: solved. Here's the function I created and does all the conditions I needed in my question. Hopefully it helps someone else: function formatPrice(number) {
  var price1 = number.toString();
  var price_length = price1.length;
  var price_pos = price_length - 2;
  var price2 = price1.substr(0, price_pos) + "." + price1.substr(price_pos);
  var price3 = Number(price2).toFixed(2);
  var price4 = price3.replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
  var formattedPrice = price4.replace(/\.00$/,'');
  return formattedPrice
}

Comment: jfiddle with solution: https://jsfiddle.net/omarel/xpvt214o/922930/